# How to create correct script which instantiating objects using factory-pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, factory-pattern

I'm creating game. There are coins which player should collect. Now I'm trying to type factory-pattern and I have 2 problems.

In the factory I need to Instantiate prefab of coin and at the same time the factory must be available from other classes. It's unlikely to get factory by its instance, so it must be static. But in this case factory can't hold link to prefab. I thought  about implementing singleton already, but in this way I should hold this script on the scene and it's look like some kind of "dirty way".

Coin.cs

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    CellCoordinates coords;
    public CellCoordinates Coords
    {
        get { return coords; }
        set
        {
            coords = value;
            transform.localPosition = coords.ToWorld();
        }
    }
    static public event System.Action OnCollect;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.2f);
            OnCollect?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

CoinFactory.cs

```
public class CoinFactory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]Coin coinPrefab;
    public Coin Create(Maze.CellCoordinates coords)
    {
        Coin coin = Instantiate(coinPrefab) as Coin;
        coin.Coords = coords;
        return coin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the code you posted the code you're using? Shouldn't it be `public static Coin Create(...)`?

Comment: It does not have to be static, it can be made accessible by static field in a class. But it's probably a dirty way too

Comment: As I wrote, if I make it static, than I can't hold link to prefab in Unity3d.
For now I change class signature to:

`
public static Coin Create(Coin coinPrefab, Coordinates coords)
`

But I don't think this way is correct. Eventually, it works. And I will be happy. if someone propose sophisticated solution))

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
public class CoinFactory : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static CoinFactory instance;

    [SerializeField] private Coin coinPrefab;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Coin Create(Maze.CellCoordinates coords)
    {
        var coin = Instantiate(instance.coinPrefab);
        coin.Coords = coords;
        return coin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate already returns a `Coin` so `as Coin` is not neccesarry

Comment: you are right, edited the answer - this was in the part copied from the question